# website content overlapping the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flask

I am following a YouTube tutorial for Flask over here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnDWIZuWYW0. I am at the part of the video where the navigation bar code is put into the application, but my website ends up overlapping the previous structure of it.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ4dt.png) is a link to my website, which is currently not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}">


    {% if title %}
        <title>Flask Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Flask Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
        <header class="site-header">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
              <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="/">Flask Blog</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/login">Login</a>
                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest                        Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-                                    light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding something as simple as a `<br>` tag? Then the text will be pushed down and not overlap.
(Edited)
Trying this newer tutorial this is a year old so the components won’t be out of date this mite also answer some of your questions about Flask.
https://youtu.be/Z1RJmh_OqeA

Comment: that works but the navigation bar does he doesn't need to do that in the video, so I am thinking it shouldnt be there.

Comment: When you followed Video does the site look like it is on the Video or is there’s bit that are different than Video?

Comment: Ok, so looked at Video myself and followed though this could be that some of the components are outdated. Try using same version as the Video or newer Video. (This Is A Guess, This could still be up to date)

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought as well. I even copied and pasted the exact code from his github and it still showed wrong colors and messed up borders.

Comment: Have you looked at updated video? This should be a solution.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make some bottom spacing on the bottom of the container? Then it won't collapse.

```
#container {
margin-bottom : 5uv; // uv / em/ px/ % / chose whatever you need
}
```

Also: Try to see if your container or anything else in the CSS corresponding to the navbar is declared as `position: absolute`

Comment: thanks for the response but where would i insert the "#container...." code you suggested? I am completely new to HTML as well

Comment: In your CSS file main.css or in your HTML file between <style> </style>

Comment: which container's bottom would i insert the code in? Also I have tried to change the colors corresponding to the navbar in main.css to look like the video but it doesnt work.

Comment: It's not updating directly? Are you working in local or on a dedicated server ?

Comment: Working in a local server and using flask. I even copied the code from his actual GitHub and it's still not the same. Can you try it on your part?